# launch chrome extension from command line

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension which opens a new tab window,plays youtube videos and collects the network statistics.

What I currently do is to launch the chrome and then click the extension icon to run the extension. Now I want to automate the process of launching chrome and the extension simultaneously from command line.

Please guide me how I can open and run the extension on chrome from command line.

I have tried --load-and-launch-app  and  --load-extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the logic of your extension in your `background.js` page. In this way when chrome starts, it will run your code in `background.js` without clicking extension icon.

For starting chrome use -

```
start chrome
```